# Call member constructor in copy constructor definition

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the copy constructor in c++ and I want to define my own copy constructor as I have a pointer member in my class so I need a deep copy.
Suppose this:

`communicate.h`:

```
#ifndef communicate_h
#define communicate_h

#include "mbed.h"

class Communicate
{
private:
    /* data */
    BufferedSerial serial;
    FILE *serial_stream;
public:
    Communicate(const PinName Tx, const PinName Rx, const int baud);
    Communicate(const Communicate& source);
    ~Communicate();
};
#endif
```

`communicate.cpp`:

```
#include "communicate.h"


Communicate::Communicate(const PinName Tx, const PinName Rx, const int baud): serial(Tx, Rx, baud)
{
    serial.set_blocking(false);
    serial_stream = new FILE;
    serial_stream = fdopen(&serial, "w+");
}

Communicate::~Communicate()
{
    delete serial_stream;
}

// copy constructor
Communicate::Communicate(const Communicate& source)
{
    serial = source.serial;
    serial_stream = new FILE;
    *serial_stream = *source.serial_stream;
}
```

And I get this:

```
Compile [ 99.5%]: communicate.cpp
[Error] communicate.cpp@17,51: no matching function for call to 'mbed::BufferedSerial::BufferedSerial()'
[Error] communicate.cpp@19,21: use of deleted function 'mbed::BufferedSerial& mbed::BufferedSerial::operator=(const mbed::BufferedSerial&)'
[Error] BufferedSerial.h@52,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::SerialBase& mbed::SerialBase::operator=(const mbed::SerialBase&)'
[Error] SerialBase.h@46,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::NonCopyable<T>& mbed::NonCopyable<T>::operator=(const mbed::NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = mbed::SerialBase]'
[Error] SerialBase.h@46,7: non-static const member 'const PinName mbed::SerialBase::_tx_pin', can't use default assignment operator
[Error] SerialBase.h@46,7: non-static const member 'const PinName mbed::SerialBase::_rx_pin', can't use default assignment operator
[Error] BufferedSerial.h@52,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::FileHandle& mbed::FileHandle::operator=(const mbed::FileHandle&)'
[Error] FileHandle.h@46,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::NonCopyable<T>& mbed::NonCopyable<T>::operator=(const mbed::NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = mbed::FileHandle]'
[Error] BufferedSerial.h@52,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::NonCopyable<T>& mbed::NonCopyable<T>::operator=(const mbed::NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = mbed::BufferedSerial]'
[Error] BufferedSerial.h@52,7: use of deleted function 'rtos::Mutex& rtos::Mutex::operator=(const rtos::Mutex&)'
[Error] Mutex.h@70,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::NonCopyable<T>& mbed::NonCopyable<T>::operator=(const mbed::NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = rtos::Mutex]'
```

The error complains about not calling the constructor of BufferedSerial class in the copy constructor of `Communicate` class and on the other hand, I can't simply put the `: serial(Tx, Rx, baud)` in front of copy constructor definition.

I'm not sure how to call the member constructor in the copy constructor definition.

Comment: That's not how you work with the C `FILE*` I/O interface.

Comment: It's not complaining about not calling the constructor, it's complaining about there not being a default constructor or an assignment operator. It looks like `BufferedSerial` is not copyable (which seems reasonable) and you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks. But if I don't use my own copy constructor how it uses the default copy constructor of `BufferedSerial`?

Comment: It doesn't use that copy constructor – there isn't one. All those "NonCopyable" you see among the errors mean exactly what they say; you can't copy a `BufferedSerial`, ever. You need to change your code so that you don't try.

Comment: @molbdnilo So you mean if I need to implement the copy constructor I need to make sure that all class members have copy constructor implemented right? And here I can't use my own copy constructor as `BufferedSerial` don't have one.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to copy an object, all its members must be copyable, or be replaceable with new objects in a sensible way in the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that `BufferedSerial` is not copy assignable:

```
[Error] communicate.cpp@17,51: no matching function for call to 'mbed::BufferedSerial::BufferedSerial()'
[Error] communicate.cpp@19,21: use of deleted function 'mbed::BufferedSerial& mbed::BufferedSerial::operator=(const mbed::BufferedSerial&)'
```

At the end of the error message you see:

```
[Error] Mutex.h@70,7: use of deleted function 'mbed::NonCopyable<T>& mbed::NonCopyable<T>::operator=(const mbed::NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = rtos::Mutex]'
```

A class is only default copy construct and copy assignable if all its members are. Due to how a mutex works, it is not copyable, and because mutex is used by one of the members of `BufferedSerial` the `BufferedSerial` itself won't be copy construct and copy assignable by default, and your `Communicate` shouldn't be either due to that.

If you want to write a copy constructor and copy assignment operator for your class, then you need to figure out how you can have two distinct `FILE` that work on the same file/pipe, which normally does not make much sense (or how to share them between instances). Because if you do that, especially with a `w+` you most certainly run into problems with data corruption if the stream is buffered (another reason why it would most certainly not be copyable even if mutex is not used).

This indicates that you might have a misconception in your design.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in the first line in the body of your copy constructor, on the right hand side: given that `serial` is a private element of the class, you cannot access `serial` from the `Communicate` object you set to copy from. You need to define some `get()` function and copy from it.

Comment: They all are accessible within the class member functions. Look at the c'tor's definition, the `serial` was used in it and it's accessible.

Comment: `serial` in the constructor's initialization list is a private data member, yes, but does belong to the `this` object, so it is ok to access. On the other hand, in the copy costructor, OP is trying to access private member data `serial` of another `Communicate` object, the one he wants to copy in `this`. He should not have access to private members of objects other than `this`.